# content://sms/ address column not always return "sender's" number

Tags: android, sms

When I query the "content://sms/" content provider and pull information from the address column; I always get the phone number that the message is "from" or "sent to".  If I receive a message, then address is the number from the other person's phone.  When I send a message, then address is the message I am sending to.

How do I differentiate if a message in "content://sms/" folder is a sent message or received message without querying the respective inbox/sent folders?

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body" };
    String selection = "thread_id = " + threadId;
    String sortOrder = "date DESC";
    String limit = "LIMIT " + String.valueOf(mItemsOnPage);

    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String deviceNumber = tm.getLine1Number();

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, columns, selection, null,
            sortOrder + " " + limit);

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToLast();

        while (!cursor.isBeforeFirst()) {
            long messageId = cursor.getLong(0);
            String address = cursor.getString(2);
            long date = cursor.getLong(4);
            String body = cursor.getString(5);
            long person = cursor.getLong(3);
            cursor.moveToPrevious();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the column `type` in your query. It contains a *long* indicating whether you are dealing with a received (`type == 1`) or sent (`type == 2`) message.

This way you'll know how to interpret the address column.

Comment: i was aware of this column, but thought it would differentiate between mms and sms.  thanks a lot.

Comment: would you happen to know what a type 5 message would be?

Comment: @Justin see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html#MESSAGE_TYPE_ALL for all the related constants

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final Uri SMS_Inbox = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
public static final Uri SMS_Sent = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
public static final Uri SMS_draft = Uri.parse("content://sms/draft");
public static final Uri SMS_Queued = Uri.parse("content://sms/queued");
public static final Uri SMS_ALL = Uri.parse("content://sms/");

public static final int INBOX = 1;
public static final int SEND = 2;
public static final int DRAFT = 3;
public static final int QUEUED = 6;
```

Answer (score -2):

type 5 seems to be a draft message type (for samsung i9100 at least)