# SMS numbers are incorrect?

Tags: android, dropbox

I am using this code to retrieve the SMS from Emulator.After that I need to Post it in to the DropBox.I saved some messages to Emulator, it retrieves two things Number and Body.At the time of retrieval it displays the
**Wrong Numbers** but correct Body. How to correct the number, I save the numbers in to a variable **Number**. My code is here, I am using 2.1 version.

**code**

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
while(c.moveToNext()){

Number = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));

Body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();

smslist.add( Number + ":" +"\n"+ Body);
    }
itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

c.close();
```

Any solution ?

Comment: What it is displaying in place of number.. and where you are displaying number

Comment: try to use: String number=dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")); and yes,you must use variable name starting with small letter.

Comment: Displaying number in the ListView  ...  instead of coming the Saved number it comes  some other numbers

Comment: I send message using the Emulator properties to my AVD,Is any way to display the name if the number already exist in the contact, if it is not in contact it display the number

Comment: Please add What number it is showing. And add code for printing it. Have a look on my answer . you need to change some of your code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code  you are using

```
Number = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
```

use `c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"))` Method instead of `getInt()` method

see below link too,  The type column in SMS uri

[retrieving number.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343383/519718)

Comment: Thanks Ankit.I got the correct answer now.It display all the SMS with numbers,The number is the 10digit Mobile number , I saved some numbers in the Emulator as a contact with particular names, But on display it shows the numbers only instead of names for that contact.why it happends...it won't come names ?

Comment: If it solved your problem mark it as accepted. For second issue, you need to fetch contact name from COntacts content provider via number one by one. Mark this answer as accepted, Post another question on StackO. Give link here i will post another answer there.

Comment: sure , thanks for your reply...Actually the problem is I didn't use the Contact Content provider yet.

Comment: Will tell you how to do it. Post a question

Comment: Names not displayed on Retrieving SMS details?  is my question

Answer (score 0):

Treat the address as String instead of a Int.

I think it should resolve the issue.

String str = cursor.getString( c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));

regards,

dattatray.

Comment: Dattatray.......I got the answer I know where was the error actually..thanks..but it didn't show the names for the number I saved it in the Emulator